# Retrieving URL folder name from string

Tags: php, url

I am having a slight trouble. I am wanting to get a find the top level folder and use it as a variable.

For instance.

If I have a url: http://www.someurl.com/foldername/hello.php

I would like to look at the URL and echo 'foldername'.

At present my code strips things so that it echos 'hello.php'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

// Get URL String // 
function curPageURL() {
$pageURL = 'http';
if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
$pageURL .= "://";
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
$pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
} else {
$pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}
return $pageURL;
}

// Split String and get folder//

function curPageName() {
return substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/"));
}

// Pass along Results //
$foldername = curPageName();

echo $foldername;

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
          <?php 

            $a = "http://www.someurl.com/foldername/hello.php";

            $b =  explode('/',$a);

            //var_dump($b); 

        // i got this result  array(5) { [0]=> string(5) "http:" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=>                  string(15) "www.someurl.com" [3]=> string(10) "foldername" [4]=> string(9) "hello.php" }
```

// now to get or echo foldername store the value from the array in a variable

```
         $value = $b['3'];

        echo $value // will output foldername 
      ?>
```

i am a newbie too

Comment: That's a great result and what I was looking for. The only trouble I have is to dynamically feed the URL into the $a. e.g. $a = "$url";  so I am sure from here I can put something together.

Comment: ya whatever url value you are getting you can store it in $a and get you answer . dont forget to accept or upvote the answer if it has helped you :)

Comment: you can get url look at this method here http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/27.html

Comment: Cheers Rinzler! Very stoked with your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try it with

```
$parse = parse_url('http://www.someurl.com/foldername/hello.php')
echo dirname($parse['path']);
// Output: /foldername
// use trim() to strip of that leading slash
```

Answer (score 1):

Should we do so tough?

i think this would do

```
function getFolderName($URL)
{
        $pieces  = explode("/",$URL);
    //    return $pieces[3];// -->do this if you  need folder after domain
    return $pieces[count($pieces)-2]; //-->do this if you need folder just before sourcefile
}
```

Comment: This will return the second last instead of the first part of the path after the hostname. Consider the `url http://somedomain.com/foldername/otherfolder/hello.php` where the function proposed by you will deliver `otherfolder` instead of `foldername`

Comment: no, it will return the folder name just before the source file.

Comment: It will return path before the source file and i think that is what the original poster wanted.